# Get selected node's parent in FancyTree

Tags: javascript, jquery, fancytree

I'm working on FancyTree.js for my current project. I need a simple 
requirement in the Tree.

My requirement is I need to get current selected node's parent node.
I'm searching everything, but I can't find the solution.

[This link about FancyTreeApi](http://wwwendt.de/tech/fancytree/demo/sample-api.html) has many options. But none of those are related to my requirement.

**EDITED**

I have done to get the current selected node using the below code.

```
 var node = $("#tree").fancytree("getActiveNode");
  if( node ){
    alert("Currently active: " + node.title);
  }else{
    alert("No active node.");
  }
```

Comment: Show us what did you try?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have researched your question and you can do it in some ways:

**First:**

```
  var node = $("#tree").fancytree("getActiveNode");
  if( node ){
    console.log("Parent of FancytreeNode type: ");
    console.dir(node.parent);
  }else{
    console.log("No active node.");
  }
```

where `node.parent` is parent tree node

**Second:**

```
  var node = $("#tree").fancytree("getActiveNode");
  if( node ){
    console.log("Parent of HTMLElement type: ");
    console.dir(node.li.parentNode);
  }else{
    console.log("No active node.");
  }
```

where `node.li` is HTML element of active tree node and `node.li.parentNode` is it's parent HTML element

Comment: Thank you very much for your help.And it is Working Great for me :) Thank's once again.I'm using the First method  you have to write.

Answer (score 1):

Use Below code

This Should be also helpful For You

```
var node = $("#tree").fancytree("getActiveNode");
 if( node ){
  alert(node.parent);//Give Detail about the parent
  alert(node.parent.title);//Give parent node Name
  }else{
   alert("Select a node First");
 }
```